# Shopee returning error in api v2: error_auth - No permission. Please go to Shopee Seller Center to pass the shop KYC verification; what to do?

Tags: java, api, rest

I was integrating shopee's v2 api into my system, but it's returning a json with this error:

```json
{
  "request_id": "118584ece184b9b2a1cc70596bc7493f",
  "error": "error_auth",
  "message": "No permission. Please go to Shopee Seller Center to pass the shop KYC verification first, then this shop can call for this API."
}
```

I'm using the test account that Shopee gives us, I've already filled in the data at Shopee Seller Center, I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After communicating with shopee, it was determined that it was a system bug, and the problem of creating a new app and testing account was resolved.